# Syntax logic suggestions

Tags: html, functional-programming, syntax

This syntax will be used inside HTML attributes. Here are a few examples of what I have so far:

```
<input name="a" conditions="!b, c" />
<input name="b" />
<input name="c" />
```

This will make input "a" do something if `b` is not checked and `c` is checked (b and c  are assumed to be checkboxes if they don't have a `:value` defined)

---

```
<input name="a" conditions="!b:foo|bar, c:foo" />
<input name="b" />
<input name="c" />
```

This will make input "a" do something if `b`doesn't have `foo` or `bar` values, and if `c` has the `foo` value.

---

```
<input name="a" conditions="!b:EMPTY" />
<input name="b" />
```

Makes input "a" do something if `b` has a value assigned.

---

So, essentially `,` acts as logical AND, `:` as equals (=), `!` as  NOT, and `|` as OR. The `|` (OR) is only needed between values (at least I think so), and AND is not needed between values for obvious reasons :)

`EMPTY` means empty value, like `<input value="" />`

Do you have any suggestions on improving this syntax, like making it more human friendly? For example I think the "EMPTY" keyword is not really appropriate and should be replaced with a character, but I don't know which one to choose.

Comment: Are you reinventing regular expressions? Regex uses `^$` (start of input, followed by end of input) for the empty string.

Comment: I don't think regular expressions are appropriate in this case. For one thing, the syntax must be extremely simple and easy.

Comment: The syntax you suggest is not exactly light either ;) And even if you adjust the syntax (a bad idea unless you have a very good reason), you can keep the semantics which likely trumpf anything you can come up with.

Comment: wy do you feel the need to create a programming language on top of XML (a markup language)

Comment: well, I'm open to new suggestions :) I didn't find a better place for this...

Comment: Whatever you do otherwise, avoid using custom attribute names like `conditions` that may some day cause confusion with new (standard or browser-specific) attributes that might be added to HTML. Instead, use `data-` attributes, like `data-conditions`, as per HTML5 drafts; they are virtually guaranteed to remain unassigned, to be available for “private use.”

Comment: Why would you not use JavaScript?

Comment: I am, but I want to make this more abstract .I don't want to manually add js code every time I need to do something..

Comment: So instead you create a regex expy. Yeah, perfectly simple. What if further needs arise, say, error messages? Still sure that this will be simpler than five lines of JS+jQuery?

Comment: there won't be need for error messages, and even if it would, I can just throw a javascript event somewhere on which I can hook error checking functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbols as you use are compact, but they are not friendly. If you are aiming this meta language at developers, then I think it is reasonably simple, as it is based upon punctuation familiar to programmers.

But that is not your aim. You appear to be targeting this language at end users or designers, in which case your syntax is not simple at all. They have no background to imply that ! = not, | = OR.

I would think hard about your target market, and try to find a language that they know (CSS perhaps?) and base your metalanguage around the idioms used in a language they are familiar with, or on basic English and Math (or, and, not, =).

While I cannot be sure that this is appropriate for your end users (that is your call, not mine) I would think that something like this would be a better fit for non-programmers. These are re-writes of the exact examples you used.

- `b = FALSE, c = TRUE`
- `NOT b = foo OR bar, c = foo` (alternately: `b = NOT foo, b = NOT bar, c = foo` if you don't want to support NOT on the left side of the expression)
- `b = NOT BLANK`

You may choose to identify your reserved words differently than CAPS as I used ($or, $blank, $true), but the aim is to be expressive, not compact.

Comment: the problem with words, is that when I'm parsing the syntax in javascript I'm using `.split('keyword')`, and I could easily split the string in the wrong place if a input has "or", "not" etc as value. With characters like !,|,: it's easier because input values and names should not contain such characters

Comment: Then write a real parser.

Comment: If someone has not written a full parser, then asking them to is not a trivial task. That said, if you want to create a language @Anna, you are going to have to deal with the fact that naive pattern matching will only get you a little way; you will need to deal with creating a full parser eventually. As soon as you roll out version 1, you will have users building complex expressions that break your simple pattern engine. Be ready for the jump to a full parser, because it will need to happen eventually.

Comment: This is effectively what [RPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG) does (which was designed, pretty much, for non-technical types).